# Python tkinter checkbutton value always equal to 0

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter

I put the `checkbutton` on the `text` widget, but everytime I select a `checkbutton`, the function `checkbutton_value` is called, and it returns 0.

Part of the code is :

```
def callback():

    file_name=askopenfilename()
    column_1rowname,column_name=draw_column(file_name)

    root = Tk()
    root.resizable(width=False,height=False)
    root.wm_title("Column")


    S = Scrollbar(root,orient="vertical")
    text=Text(root,width=15,height=10,yscrollcommand=S.set)
    S.config(command=text.yview)
    S.pack(side="right",fill="y")
    text.pack(side="left",fill="both",expand=True)

    #check the value of the checkbutton
    def checkbutton_value():

        if(var.get()):

            print 1
        else:

            print 0

    var=BooleanVar()
    chk = Checkbutton(root, text=column_1rowname[1], variable=var, command=checkbutton_value)
    text.window_create("end", window=chk)
    text.config(state=DISABLED)


errmsg='Error!'
Button(text='File Open',command=callback).pack(fill=X)


mainloop()
```

Comment: Please read http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks.I have changed it.

Comment: Is this really your real code? It's definitely a problem to create an instance of `Tk` inside a callback.

Comment: Yes.My code can run.But it always return 0 when I select the checkbutton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have more than one root window. You should only ever create exactly one instance of `Tk`, and call `mainloop` exactly once. If you need additional windows, create instances of `Toplevel`.

Each root window (and all of its children, and all related `StringVar`s etc.) start a new, *independent* tcl interpreter. Widgets and variables associated with this window can't be used in another tcl interpreter. In your case, the `StringVar` is associated with the first root window, but the widget is associated with the second. You can't share data between root windows like that.

Comment: Thanks.  The aim of this code is:firstly open a excel file,secondly choose the column.

Comment: @wxd: the aim of your code doesn't matter. You can't have two root windows. Your widget is in the second root window, but your variable belongs to the first. You can't share data between two root windows.

Comment: Any detail suggestions to change the structure of the code?I'm new to it.Thanks.

Comment: @wxd: I already wrote a suggestion: if you need more than one window, use `Toplevel` rather than creating a new instance of `Tk`.

Comment: Thanks.I will try my best to understand it.